# Form is submitted before DOM field is filled?

Tags: javascript, forms

In JavaScript I use this to fill an input field called 'XML' and then submit the form :

```
document.clientform.XML.value = XMLobject.ToString();

submitbutton=document.getElementById('submitbutton');
submitbutton.click();
```

`XMLobject` is an object that holds an XML document. With `ToString()` you get the entire XML as a string.

Now some clients, using IE8, are complaining that sometimes the value of field XML is empty.

Could it be possible that the form was already submitted before the input field was written?

Or is it absolutely impossible in this situation that `submitbutton` was clicked before `XML.ToString()` was ready with its work?

Comment: Is it possible to submit the form without going through your code?  What happens if you fill the XML field in the form's `onsubmit` event?

Answer (score 0):

What @robertc said is true, your form is submitting before you code are executed or may it can be submitted in other event/moment ?

So you can change to call your function on `onsubmit` event, will make more sense. Then you'll no longer need to call `click()` on submit button, just this:

`document.clientform.XML.value = XMLobject.ToString();`

Where do you call this function? Isn't on a submit button, right ? Because if it is called on a submit button, I may submitting your form before passing through the function.

Just some hypotheses...

Answer (score 0):

A likely possibility is that the XMLObject.ToString() sometimes fails or produces empty result. It's also possible that the form is somehow submitted without you're code getting executed. If you try to execute you're code by handling the onsubmit event of forms then you can ensure that no matter what you're code will execute before the form is sent to the serve.